# Writing into a nested schema for Realm

Tags: nested, realm, schema, realm-list

Based on my api response I made my schema for realm but I'm not able to push values into realm according to schema. plase let me know is there any way to do like this

```
 export const WORKFLOW_SCHEMA = 'work_flow';
export const WORKFLOW_NAMES_SCHEMA = 'workflow_name';
export const WorkflowNamesSchema = {
   name: WORKFLOW_SCHEMA,
   primaryKey :'workflow_Name',
   properties: {
     workflow_Name: 'string',
     default_State: 'int',
     states: { type: 'list', objectType: WORKFLOW_NAMES_SCHEMA }
   }
 };

export const NEXTSTATE_SCHEMA = 'next_states';
export const WorkFlowSchema = {
  name: WORKFLOW_NAMES_SCHEMA,
  primaryKey :'state_ID',
  properties: {
    state_ID: 'int',
    action_Name: 'string',
    state: 'string',
    next_States: { type: 'list', objectType: NEXTSTATE_SCHEMA }
  }
};

export const NextStatesSchema = {
  name: NEXTSTATE_SCHEMA,
  properties: {
    action: 'string',
    state: 'string',
  },
};
```

Comment: Your realm schema is based on the objects you store in Realm. What are you asking here?

Comment: Realm.open({schema: [Car, Person]})
  .then(realm => {
    // ...use the realm instance here
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error here if something went wrong
  });
here they mentioned about only Car and Person if we have another 
Realm.open({schema: [Car, Person,Next]})
  .then(/* ... */);
how to push values into this nested schema

Comment: Please put code and additional information *in your question*. What you're asking is still unclear.